# Least squares problem with constrained solution

Tags: matrices, na.numerical-analysis, quadratic-programming, least-squares

If $a_{m\times 1}$ and $Q_{m\times n}$ ($m<n $) are known, and we know every element of $b$ is between $[-1\ \ 1]$, how to determine $b$ to minimize $\|a+Qb\|_2$?

Comment: Solve it as a quadratic program (using an iterative algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

There is an algorithm designed specifically for the OP's problem, given in [Bounded-Variable Least-Squares: an Algorithm and Applications](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/Preprints/bvls.pdf) [pdf]:

> BVLS (bounded-variable least-squares) is modelled on NNLS and solves the problem 
>   \begin{equation} \min_{l \leq x \leq u} \|A x - b\|_2,  \end{equation}
>   where $l,x,u \in \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix.